# show first name and last name in two textbox?

Tags: vba, vb6

```
  Dim myName As String
    Dim firstName As String
    Dim lastName As String
    Dim space As Integer
    Dim nameLen As Integer
    myName = txtName.Text
    firstName = txtFirstName.Text
    lastName = txtLastName.Text
    nameLen = Len(myName)
    space = InStr(myName, " ")
    Do Until space > 0
        firstName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(myName, space - 1)
        lastName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(myName, nameLen - space)
    Loop
    txtFirstName.Text = firstName
    txtLastName.Text = lastName
```

As the code I wrote, I tried to use len function, InStr function, left and right function to make a program to show first and last name in separate textbox. However, when I put any full name, and click parse name button. the first name and last will not show up in two textbox. Can anyone please help me to correct it? I'd be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim myName As String
Dim firstName As String
Dim lastName As String
Dim space As Integer
Dim nameLen As Integer
myName = txtName.Text
firstName = txtFirstName.Text
lastName = txtLastName.Text
nameLen = Len(myName)
space = InStr(myName, " ")
firstName = VBA.Strings.Left(myName, space - 1)
lastName = Right(myName, nameLen - space)
txtFirstName.Text = firstName
txtLastName.Text = lastName
```

Comment: left() and right() will shows: 'Public Property Left As integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed...

Comment: Ah, you have another identifier called `Left`. In that case, the full name in VBA is `VBA.Strings.Left`. The name you used, `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left` only works in VB.NET.

Comment: If you have that problem with any other string function, the solution is the same - add `VBA.Strings.` to the beginning of it. For functions other than string functions, check the object browser to find out what the full name is.

Comment: Happy Thanksgiving! And please accept this answer if it resolves your question.